Sending HTTP Request using MS XML, 6.0 Library with a Dynamic/Partially Known URL -loop
I am trying to loop through pitchers' game logs on www.statmuse.com. The main issue is that, since I am trying to do this on a loop, part of the URL is currently unknown.
For example, looking at Martín Pérez's 2024 game logs, the URL is: https://www.statmuse.com/mlb/player/martin-perez-46483/game-log
now while trying to loop through different pitchers, this 5-digit number sequence (46483 in my example) is variable and changes between each pitcher's game log.
I have put together the below code. The issue, of course, is looping through 10000 and 99999 in attempt to find the correct 5-digit number sequence, which is causing my excel to crash and not respond. Can anyone please advise a more efficient way to achieve this? I apologize, this is my first project with HTTP Requests and anything of the like, so I am sure the code is a bloody mess.
code:
Dim ws As Worksheet, PLws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set PLws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pitcher List T")

Set rng = PLws.Range("B1:B1")
For Each cc In rng

    Dim httpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60:    Set httpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmldoc As HTMLDocument:            Set htmldoc = New HTMLDocument
    
    playerName = CStr(cc.Value)
    Dim baseURL As String
    baseURL = "https://www.statmuse.com/mlb/player/" & playerName & "-"

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim startNumber As Long
    Dim endNumber As Long
    startNumber = 10000 ' this loop is the issue (i think)
    endNumber = 99999   ' this loop is the issue (i think)

Dim i As Long, target As Long
For i = startNumber To endNumber ' this loop is the issue (i think)

    Dim url As String
    url = baseURL & CStr(i) & "/game-log"
    
    If CheckUrlExists(url) Then
        target = i
        Debug.Print "the target i is: " & target
    End If

Next i
    
    Dim Murl As String
    Murl = baseURL & target & "/game-log"
    
    httpRequest.Open "GET", Murl, False
    httpRequest.send
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText

this is the function:
Public Function CheckUrlExists(url) As Boolean
        
    On Error GoTo CheckUrlExists_Error
    
    Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60:    Set xmlhttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmldoc As HTMLDocument:            Set htmldoc = New HTMLDocument
    Dim H2el As Object
    
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlhttp.send
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
    
    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        For Each H2el In htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("h2")
            If InStr(1, ChangeAccent(H2el.innerText), CStr(cc.Offset(0, -1).Value)) > 0 Then
                CheckUrlExists = True
            End If
        Next H2el
    Else
        CheckUrlExists = False
    End If
    
    Exit Function
    
CheckUrlExists_Error:
    CheckUrlExists = False
    
End Function

thank you

Please share the code in Function CheckUrlExists().

ive updated the question to include the function

You're making two calls when you only need one...  This approach is still kind of a rude thing to do to the site though.

my apologies Tim, as I said this my first time working with https requests, and I am very open to as much guidance as possible. Excuse my ignorance, but how is it rude to the site? Unnecessary & additional wear and tear to the site's response mechanism?

can you please lead me in the right direction of how to send a request properly? And, if it is possible, how to achieve the wildcard URL without damaging the site or sending too many requests?

Just get the URL directly with:
Function GetPlayerLogURLs(ByRef playerName As Variant) As Collection
    Dim httpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set httpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Const baseURL As String = "https://www.statmuse.com"
    '
    httpRequest.Open "POST", baseURL & "/ask", False
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    httpRequest.send "question%5Bquery%5D=" _
                   & LCase$(Replace(playerName, " ", "+")) _
                   & "&question%5Bpreferred_domain%5D=&question%5Bconversation_token%5D="
    '
    Dim response As String: response = httpRequest.responseText
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim res As New Collection
    Dim temp As String
    '
    i = InStr(1, response, "/game-log""")
    If i = 0 Then
        i = InStr(1, response, """/mlb/player/")
        On Error Resume Next
        Do While i > 0
            j = InStr(i + 1, response, """")
            If j > 0 Then
                temp = baseURL & Mid$(response, i + 1, j - i - 1) & "/game-log"
                res.Add temp, temp
            End If
            i = InStr(j + 1, response, """/mlb/player/")
        Loop
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        j = InStrRev(response, """", i)
        If j > 0 Then res.Add baseURL & Mid$(response, j + 1, i - j + 8)
    End If
    Set GetPlayerLogURLs = res
End Function

and then just use it like this:
Sub TestPlayerURLs()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim w As Variant
    Dim coll As Collection
    '
    For Each v In Array("Martin Perez", "Derrick White", "Logan Allen", "This name doesn't exist")
        Debug.Print "Player name: " & v
        Set coll = GetPlayerLogURLs(v)
        Debug.Print "Results found: " & coll.Count
        For Each w In coll
            Debug.Print w
        Next w
        Debug.Print
    Next v
End Sub


if you have the time, could you answer one more question. How would I account for if there are players that have the same name? For example. Logan Allen on the Diamondbacks (https://www.statmuse.com/mlb/player/logan-allen-90330/game-log), and Logan Allen on the Guardians (https://www.statmuse.com/mlb/player/logan-allen-92509/game-log)? Right now, the function returns nothing in this scenario, I am assuming because there are multiple results. Thank you for your time.

@Kurt I edited the answer. the function now returns a Collection object with 0, 1 or multiple responses

@CristianBuse Very neat solution. May I ask a simple question: how to figure out the arguement of send ? eg. "&question%5Bpreferred_domain%5D=&question%5Bconversation_token%5D=" in your code.

@taller Certainly. In your Browser, use Developer tools. For Chrome press F12 key. Then go to Network tab and start recording. Then whatever actions you do, they get recorded and you can then examine each GET or POST request. You will be able to see Request Headers, URLs, form content, responses etc.

@CristianBuse  Any idea why this was working perfectly for me this morning, and now, after about an hour of testing and tailoring the results to my worksheet, it is not returning a URL even in the simple debug.print test?

@Kurt I just tested and it still works for me. You must have done too many requests within a short period of time. Try changing your IP address - e.g. use a VPN

@CristianBuse sorry to keep following up here. I am quite inexperienced with HTTP requests. In my free time, I've been trying to adapt what you provided me to work with "https://www.mlb.com/player/colton-cowser-681297" and retrieving the numeric player ID from MLB' site... could you please provide some direction, if you don't mind?

@Kurt Just do a GET request to their API. Something like this: httpRequest.Open "Get", "https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/sports/1/players?fields=people,fullName,lastName,nameSlug&season=2024", False and then httpRequest.send. You can also set the header before calling send with httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json". The returned json has all the IDs you need.

much appreciated @CristianBuse


The sequence number in URL is not always 5-digits. eg.


https://www.statmuse.com/nba/player/lebron-james-1780


For each POST request, the remote server's response time for 200 (OK) or 502 (Bad Gateway) status codes varies. In my testing, it typically takes between half a second to one second. Validating 90,000 URLs using this method is not practical.

Indeed, attempting to validate a large number of URLs could place a significant burden on the website's servers. In fact, it could be interpreted as a form of minor DDoS (Distributed Denial of Service) attack.

The code below simulates a search on https://www.statmuse.com/ using Internet Explorer, which although a bit outdated, still gets the job done. Selenium WebDriver might be a better alternative.


Sub Demo()
    Debug.Print GetURL("martin perez")
    Debug.Print GetURL("lebron james")
End Sub
Function GetURL(ByVal sFullName As String) As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    ' Initialize Internet Explorer
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False
    ' Navigate to the webpage
    IE.Navigate "https://www.statmuse.com/ask?q=" & Replace(sFullName, " ", "-")
    ' Wait for IE to finish loading the page
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ' Get the document object
    Set doc = IE.Document
    ' Get the HTML content of the webpage
    'Dim htmlContent As String:  htmlContent = doc.DocumentElement.outerHTML
    Dim oLink As Object
    Set oLink = doc.getElementsByTagName("link")(0)
    ' Extract the href attribute value from the link tag
    If Not oLink Is Nothing Then
        GetURL = oLink.getAttribute("href")
    Else
        GetURL = ""
    End If
    ' Close IE
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Function

Output in Immediate Window:
https://www.statmuse.com/mlb/player/mart%C3%ADn-p%C3%A9rez-46483
https://www.statmuse.com/nba/player/lebron-james-1780


thank you, I got a run time error "automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients" on line " Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4" and I have made enabled the appropriate references for IE controls.

I'm not sure what does the error mean. I've tested the code without issues on Win11+O365.
